Limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1/2} - \ln(n+1/2)$
I am trying to understand the limit of the following expression as $n \to \infty$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1/2} - \ln(n+1/2)$$
Numerical investigation suggests that the limit of this expression as $n \to \infty$ is $-2 + \gamma + \ln 4$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
However, I am having trouble proving this result analytically. Can someone provide an explanation or proof for why this limit evaluates to this particular value?
I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to approach the analysis of this limit. Thank you in advance for your help!

Try to use the definition of the $\gamma$ and consider the separation of $\sum \frac{2}{2k + 1} = 2\left[\sum \frac{1}{k} - \sum \frac{1}{2k}\right]$.

Thanks for your hint! I have got it by using the technique of the separation!

Let $\psi(z)=\Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$. Then it is known that
$$
\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}\left(\frac1n-{1\over n+z}\right),
$$
so there is
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k+\frac12}-\log\left(n+\frac12\right)\right)
&=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\left({1\over k+\frac12}-\frac1k\right)-\log{n+\frac12\over n}\right]+\gamma \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left({1\over k+\frac12}-\frac1k\right)+\gamma=-\psi\left(\frac12+1\right).
\end{aligned}
To compute $\psi\left(\frac12+1\right)$, notice that
$$
\psi\left(\frac12\right)=-2\log2-\gamma,\quad\psi\left(z+1\right)=\psi(z)+\frac1z,
$$
so there is
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k+\frac12}-\log\left(n+\frac12\right)\right)=-2+\gamma+\log4.
$$

Thanks for your answer! Though I am not familiar with the approach you have just given, I will try to learn something related. Thanks again!

Considering the hint provided by @openspace, I have got the correct result.
\begin{align*}
            \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{2}} - \ln(n+\frac{1}{2}) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}2(\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{k} -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} -1) -\ln(2n+1) +\ln 2\\
            &= \lim_{n\to\infty}2(\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{k} -\ln(2n+1)) -(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} -\ln n) +\ln\frac{2n+1}{n} -2 +\ln 2\\
            &= 2\gamma -\gamma +\ln 2 -2 +\ln 2\\
            &= -2 +\gamma +\ln 4
        \end{align*}
